# Angular '/' route not working with Express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm trying to serve a home view using Express/Angular, such that when the root url ('/') is accessed, a view is loaded. Right now navigating to `http://localhost:3000` displays an empty page with `<!-- ngView:  -->` and nothing else. Navigating to `http://localhost:3000/about` displays the about page as expected. How do I get the home partial to display when the root is accessed?

**app.js (w/ Express 4.9.0)**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var routes = require('./routes');
var path = path = require('path');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

**routes/routes.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
};

exports.partials = function (req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('partials/' + name);
};
```

**views/index.jade**

```
doctype
html(ng-app="myApp")
    head
        meta(charset='utf8')
        base(href='/')
        title Angular Express Seed App
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/app.css')
    body
        div(ng-controller='AppCtrl')
            div(ng-view)


        script(src='bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.js')
        script(src='bower_components/angular/angular.js')
        script(src='bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js')
        script(src='bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js')
        script(src='js/app.js')
        script(src='js/main.js')
        script(src='js/services.js')
        script(src='js/controllers.js')
        script(src='js/filters.js')
        script(src='js/directives.js')
```

**public/js/app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.controllers',
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives',
    'ngRoute'
]).
config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateURL: 'partials/home',
        controller: 'MyCtrl2'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about',
        controller: 'MyCtrl1'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I also have a `views/partials/home.jade` and a `views/partials/about.jade`

Comment: Can you access the partial page via `http://localhost:3000/partials/home`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't include the content from index.jade

Comment: Are there any errors or logs in the console when you navigate to `/`?

Comment: Nope, no errors in the server console or browser console. Of course, it works fine if I change `when('/'` to `when('/home'`, and change the otherwise to redirect to `/home`, but then when the site is accessed via the root URL, it will always change, which isn't ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have misspelled `templateUrl` in

```
when('/', {
    templateURL: 'partials/home',
    controller: 'MyCtrl2'
}).
```